# Accessing eth0 device via device on wlan0

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, bridge, access-point

I have set up a private network at work using a rasperry pi as the wireless access point. All of my wireless devices are able to connect to the network and communicate (via wlan0), however I have a Philips Hue hub that only has an ethernet port. I would like to, for example, use my phone (at 192.168.0.x) to command the hub (192.168.1.x:80) to change colors.

*/etc/network/interfaces:*

```
auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    gateway 192.168.0.0

allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 192.168.0.0
```

*/etc/dnsmasq.conf:*

```
interface=wlan0
    dhcp-range=192.168.0.2,192.168.0.20,255.255.255.0,24h
interface=eth0
    dhcp-range=192.168.1.2,192.168.1.20,255.255.255.0,24h
```

*Also in /etc/dhcpcd.conf I have included the line*

```
denyinterfaces wlan0
```

I have done a lot of research and read into forwarding with iptables (NAT), bridging using a third interface... I just have not found anyone with a problem similar to mine that deals with a wireless access point and eth0 connection in one box.

What would be the best way to accomplish my task? I would appreciate any guidance on this topic. Also, are my subnet masks and gateways set up correctly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should enable ip forwarding on your RaspberryPi `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and configure routing properly. E.g. your devices from network 192.168.0.0/24 should know the way to 192.168.1.0/24 and all devices from 192.168.1.0/24 should know way to 192.168.0.0/24.